# How to store each array value in a variable with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php
    [4] => http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checklogin.php
    [5] => http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checkupload.php
    [6] => http://www.marleenvanlook.be/contact.php
)
```

What I want to do is store each value from this array to a variable (using PHP). So for example:

```
$something1 = "http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php";
$something2 = "http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checklogin.php";
...
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You can access the array elements directly using `$arr[#]` so, for instances `echo $arr[2];` would output `http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php`. This is easier than setting up a variable for each not to mention SLIGHTLY more efficient as you won't be setting up more variables than needed.

Comment: You're clearly solving a wrong problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extract()`:

```
$data = array(
    'something1',
    'something2',
    'something3',
);
extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
echo $var0; //Output something1
```

More info on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 2):

Well.. you could do something like this?

```
$myArray = array("http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php","http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checklogin.php","etc");

$i = 0;
foreach($myArray as $value){
    ${'something'.$i} = $value;
    $i++;
    }

echo $something0; //http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php
```

This would dynamically create variables with names like `$something0`, `$something1`, etc holding a value of the array assigned in the `foreach`.

If you want the keys to be involved you can also do this:

```
$myArray = array(1 => "http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php","http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checklogin.php","etc");

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
    ${'something'.$key} = $value;
    }

echo $something1; //http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has something called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) which lets you name a variable with the value of another variable.

```
$something = array(
    'http://www.marleenvanlook.be/admin.php',
    'http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checklogin.php',
    'http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checkupload.php',
    'http://www.marleenvanlook.be/contact.php',
);

foreach($something as $key => $value) {
    $key = 'something' . $key;
    $$key = $value;

    // OR (condensed version)
    // ${"something{$key}"} = $value;
}

echo $something2;
// http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checkupload.php
```

But the question is *why* would you want to do this? [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) are meant to be accessed by keys, so you can just do:

```
echo $something[2];
// http://www.marleenvanlook.be/checkupload.php
```

Answer (score -3):

What I would do is:

```
$something1 = $the_array[2];
$something2 = $the_array[4];
```

Comment: And you would do that manually every-time a new key is added?

Comment: he asked "What I want to do is store each value from this array to a variable" - the example above is very basic.

Comment: if he wants to read though the array with a foreach loop, he can accomplish variable naming the same way also